# SQL When Selecting, change the value of one column to blank based on value in another column

Tags: sql

I have a table like

```
ID event date     
1  a     01/01/21
1  b     02/01/21
1  c     03/01/21
1  d     04/01/21
2  b     05/01/21
2  c     01/01/21
2  a     02/01/21
2  d     04/01/21
3  b     01/01/21
3  d     02/01/21
3  a     04/01/21
3  c     04/01/21
```

I would like to select everything from the table, but I would like to leave the dates for all events "a" blank.

so I want to output this in my select query

```
ID event date     
1  a     
1  b     02/01/21
1  c     03/01/21
1  d     04/01/21
2  b     05/01/21
2  c     01/01/21
2  a     
2  d     04/01/21
3  b     01/01/21
3  d     02/01/21
3  a     
3  c     04/01/21
```

What would be the simplest SQL query to get that output?

Comment: What  RDBMS you are *really* using? What have *you* tried to solve the problem? Why didn't it work? For an ANSI solution, have you considered using a `CASE` expression?

Comment: Look into CASE statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE`. For example:

```
select
  id, 
  event, 
  case when event <> 'a' then date end as date 
from t
```